# She's in my bus

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If two people take the same school bus everyday to get back home, will it be natural to use:

> She's in my bus.

Actually our teacher asked us if someone took the same bus as S. Actually we have fixed buses that we get on and off each day in order to get to school and get back home. We are dropped off at our bus stops. Does it make it sound like "a group of kids boarding the same bus", if yes then to mean this can "in" be used?

Answer (score 1):

No. It would be better to say:

> She rides/takes my bus.

or

> She rides/takes the same bus as me.

or

> She and I ride/take the same bus.

In English we say one is *on* a bus rather than *in* a bus. But saying "she is on my bus" in the present tense suggests that you are both *currently* riding on a bus.

Comment: It's fine to say "she's on my bus" when you mean "she regularly takes / is assigned to my bus".

Comment: In support of @LukeSawczak's point, this is analogous to "she's in my class" being correct even if you are not in a class at the time of speaking.

Comment: @LukeSawczak That's true, there is some grey area. I only said it "suggests" present state. All the same my midwest American ear finds my suggestions more natural.

Comment: I mean, it's actual usage in context that makes this sort of thing clear and natural. If we're in class discussing a girl and I say "She's on my bus," you know I mean generally, not currently.

Comment: So @Luke Sawczak, do you find it natural? Can you actually imagine it being used in this  context to mean what I mean?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish For my part, I can certainly imagine it. I don't think anyone would look at you funny if you said it in that context. So by that criterion I think it is fair to call it "natural."

Comment: So @TypeIA, though it might sound natural,  but is it common? Do you actually think that a native might use it instead and prefer it to other alternatives available?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Yes. I certainly used that exact phrase when I was in school. Similarly, I said things like  "She's not on my bus – she's on the Newmarket one."

Comment: @Luke Sawczak, what do you actually mean in your example sentence ? And have you others around you using it (she's on my bus) as well?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish What are you fishing for? You've got the answer - it's fine to say it and some people do say it. It seems like we're going in circles here.