# Similar sentence/omission of preposition

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

I'm in the same class you're **in**.

I'm in the same class you are.

I'm in the same class as you.

Are these sentences grammatically correct? Is the sentence in the middle, with the omitted preposition, correct as well?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/211465

Comment: The second sentence is typical of the way people speak informally. Although it might be construed as idiomatic in conversation, it should not be used in any formal or exam context.

Comment: *In* at the end more strongly implies *classroom*. The others are more likely to be used if the context is something like ***social*** *class*. Idiomatically, context would suggest one version more than the other. But if all you're asking is if they are *grammatical*, without anything else, the answer is yes. (However, it's also just proofreading.)